# Echo out the last 6 ids from database PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have this query which i think the foreach bit is wrong....

```
public function lastsixcars(){
    // this function checks whether the user name exists and if its a match
    $result = $this->db->prepare("SELECT carID FROM AutoMarket_Selling ORDER BY carID DESC LIMIT 6");
    $result->execute();

    foreach($result as $result){
       echo $car = $result['ID'];
    }
}
```

I have these on the page...

```
<a href="details.php?carID=<?php echo $car ?>">
<a href="details.php?carID=<?php echo $car ?>">
<a href="details.php?carID=<?php echo $car ?>">
<a href="details.php?carID=<?php echo $car ?>">
<a href="details.php?carID=<?php echo $car ?>">
<a href="details.php?carID=<?php echo $car ?>">
```

...and i want the last 6 IDs from the database in order as links

So...

```
<a href="details.php?carID=1st ID"> 
<a href="details.php?carID=2nd ID">
<a href="details.php?carID=3rd ID">
<a href="details.php?carID=4th ID">
<a href="details.php?carID=5th ID">
<a href="details.php?carID=6th ID">
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this please

THANKS

Comment: Then what output r u getting now ?\

Comment: I'm guessing he is getting the same output on every line..

Comment: nothing at the moment

Comment: Well there is no `ID` that you are selecting from your database to start with

Comment: Is the HTML for the linklist in the same file as the `PHP` code?

Comment: echo $car = $result['ID']; should be  echo $car = $result['carID']; i think. still nothing though

Comment: You have answers below.

Comment: Lol this guy doesn't get it.

Comment: I'v done php loads before built CMS and everything but this is the first time i have user object orientation using PDO and MVC

Answer (score 1):

make this the function

```
function lastsixcars(){
    // this function checks whether the user name exists and if its a match
    $result = $this->db->prepare("SELECT carID FROM AutoMarket_Selling ORDER BY carID DESC LIMIT 6");
    $result->execute();

    foreach($result as $results){
       $return .= '<a href="details.php?carID='.$results['carID'].'">car '.$results['carID'].'</a>';
    }

   return $return;
}
```

And this the php part

```
echo lastsixcars();
```

Comment: iv done that        
<h2 class="page-header" style="color: #27384d;">Just Listed!</h2>
<?php echo lastsixcars(); ?> but it just cuts my page off after the Just Listed! header

Answer (score 1):

use

```
   echo $car = $result['carID'];
```

In short

```
foreach($result as $result){
        echo "<a href='details.php?carID=".$result['carID']."'>Car".$result['carID']."</a>";
}
```

Comment: without telling him where/how to use it, I think his answer will be "I am already doing that"

Answer (score 0):

For the foreach part, this should work:

```
$results = array_slice($result, count($result) - 6);/* get the last 6 in the same order they are in the database*/

foreach ($results as $car) {
    echo '<a href="details.php?carID='.$car['0'].'">'; //assuming ID is the first field returned
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think it will because `$car['ID']` does not exist.